# Concatenate a single row with multiple string validations?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the query below, if both conditions are true then the last entry is updated in ErrorMessage. If one record has country more than 3 characters and length of HR_DOMAIN_Code is not equal to 3, then ErrorMessage should look like 'Invalid Country' &  'Invalid HR_DOMAIN_CODE':

```
update A     
set ErrorMessage =       
(      
 case when len(Country) > 3    then 'Invalid Country'        
 when len(HR_DOMAIN_CODE) != 3   then 'Invalid HR_DOMAIN_CODE'        
 else NULL       
 end)
```

If this possible using the case statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add another `WHEN` to handle both conditions:

```
UPDATE A
SET ErrorMessage =
    CASE
        WHEN LEN(Country) > 3 AND LEN(HR_DOMAIN_CODE) != 3 THEN 'Invalid Country & Invalid HR_DOMAIN_CODE'
        WHEN LEN(Country) > 3 THEN 'Invalid Country'
        WHEN LEN(HR_DOMAIN_CODE) != 3 THEN 'Invalid HR_DOMAIN_CODE'
        ELSE NULL
    END
```

However, the above will be very complicated once you have multiple combinations to check. My suggestion is to use a separate `CASE` expression of each of the condition. Something like this:

```
UPDATE A
SET Errormessage = STUFF((
    SELECT
        CASE WHEN LEN(Country) > 3 THEN '& Invalid Country' ELSE '' END + 
        CASE WHEN LEN(HR_DOMAIN_CODE) != 3 THEN '& Invalid HR_DOMAIN_CODE' ELSE '' END
    ), 1, 2, '')
```

Comment: Works fine when there are a few conditions but I have 30 odd and a combinations of those will be insane.

Comment: Just a small comment: you don't need `ELSE NULL`, that's the default behavior for `CASE`.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for pointing that out. It's only applicable to the first query.